# Was Voldemort pre-determined to be loveless and crave power, or did he have free will?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

The backstory is that his mother became pregnant with a love potion and therefore he was incapable of love, so my question is, did he have free will?

Comment: I don't think the manner of his conception had a role in him being incapable of love. I think that was more due to his abandonment issues. Both his parents abandoned him after all (his father by, well, abandoning him and his mother by having the audacity to just die). Growing up in a 1920's orphanage, probably still giving off strong Victorian era vibes, would have meant a clean and efficient upbringing, but an otherwise rather cold and certainly not a loving one. Essentially it would still be a nature v nurture debate, if the Gaunt blood made him inherently evil or if he could have been good.

Comment: What makes you think that, because Voldemort was conceived with the help of a love potion, he was incapable of love?

Comment: To get an answer you'd need to define "free will", many argue it doesn't exist anyhow. Then there's the issue that the question would then come out as opinion-based because of that.